# Gravity With Rects Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, rect

I really have a basic question with a long awnser needed. Can someone show me how to make a Rect jump? I just need a sample with a rectangle.

Comment: I think this is covered in Al Sweigart's [book](https://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf).

Comment: Can I have an exact page?

Comment: `gravity` is value which you add to position all the time and only collision with background stops you from falling.

Comment: see [platform_jumper.py](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=platform_jumper.py) on page [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=example_code&lang=en#section_38)

Answer (score 1):

I see your question and i think i have made some example code for you, but first i want to tell you how it works. In addition to an Y variable to store your location on the Y axis you want a variable called velocityY. For every frame in the game the Y variable is changed with velocityY like this:

```
while True:
    y += velocityY # <----- Here
    manage_window()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
          handle_event(event)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

When you jump you set velocityY to lets say -10 and that will make your rect fly off into the sky, so we need to add gravity. Here is the long example (The important part is):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

x, y = 300, 400
xVelocity, yVelocity = 0, 0
rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 200, 200)
groundRect = pygame.Rect(0, 500, 800, 100)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

white = 255, 255, 255
red = 255, 0, 0
black = 0, 0, 0
blue = 0, 0, 255

while True:
    clock.tick(60) # Make sure the game is running at 60 FPS
    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 200, 200) # Updating our rect to match coordinates
    groundRect = pygame.Rect(0, 500, 800, 100) # Creating ground rect

    # HERE IS WHAT YOU CARE ABOUT #
    yVelocity += 0.2 # Gravity is pulling the rect down
    x += xVelocity # Here we update our velocity on the X axis
    y += yVelocity # Here we update our velocity on the Y axis
    # HERE IS WHAT YOU CARE ABOUT #

    if groundRect.colliderect(rect): # Check if the rect is colliding with the ground
        y = groundRect.top-rect.height
        yVelocity = 0
    window.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, red, rect) # Here we draw the rect
    pygame.draw.rect(window, black, rect, 5) # Here we draw the black box around the rect
    pygame.draw.rect(window, blue, groundRect) # Here we draw the ground
    pygame.draw.rect(window, black, groundRect, 5) # Here we draw the black box around the rect
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # Getting events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If someone presses X on the window, then we want to quit
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE: # Pressing space will make the cube jump
                if y >= 300: # Checking if cube is on the ground and not in the air
                    yVelocity = -10 # Setting velocity to upwards
    pygame.display.flip() # Updating the screen
```

Comment: you create `rect` and groundRect` two times. you can remove second time -  inside `while`.

Comment: I keep on getting the fact that there is a lot of empty arguments. What should I put as the arguments?